# Spark hive query join error

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I have spec of cloudera cluster like this:

[image]

I create simple spark sql appliation to join hive table. The table is external table. For  healtpersonalcare_reviews table the data was written in json file and (1.7 GB) for health_ratings table the data was writen in csv format(115MB). Here is my code:

```
val warehouseLocation = "/hive/warehouse"
var args_list      = args.toList
var conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1024m")

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config(conf)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()


val table_view_name = args_list(0)
val limit = args_list(1)

val df_addjar = spark.sql("ADD JAR /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core.jar")

var df_use =spark.sql("use testing")
var df = spark.sql("SELECT hp.asin, hp.helpful,hp.overall,hp.reviewerid,hp.reviewername,hp.reviewtext,hp.reviewtime,hp.summary,hp.unixreviewtime FROM testing.healtpersonalcare_reviews hp LEFT JOIN testing.health_ratings hr ON (hp.reviewerid = hr.reviewerid) ")
var df_create_join_table = spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS healtpersonalcare_joins (asin string,helpful array<int>,overall double,reviewerid string,reviewername string,reviewtext string,reviewtime string,summary string,unixreviewtime int)")


df.cache()
df.collect().foreach(println)

System.exit(0)
```

I run the application using this command :

spark-submit --class org.sia.chapter03App.App --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1024m --driver-memory 1024m --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g --verbose /root/sparktest/original-chapter03App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar name 10

I try to use variation of value  --executor-memory and --driver-memory

1. For "--executor-memory 1024m --driver-memory 1024m" I got error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
2. For "--executor-memory 2048m --driver-memory 2048m" I got error "in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this? What's the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Adding `.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps")` in `conf` may work.

Comment: Thanks adarsh. Unfortunately I still got error "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" :(